# Compare historical data in Powershell and output the different values from yesterday to today

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv, datatables, compare

I have two tables that I need to compare the difference between today's value and yesterday's value and tell me what changed. Note: I have used "Today" and "Yesterday" instead of dates in the two tables in the image, but the actual tables have dates.

I need a Powershell script that will take DeviceName and PowerState and tell me which changed between yesterday and today. In the example, I need it to only tell me the change from yesterday to today: "Device B is Off". I will then run that script daily to send an email to my team. The script should also let me know if the device powered on from yesterday to today.

The data is in SQL, in PowerShell, I have pulled the data out of SQL and into two separate CSVs then imported each CSV into two separate arrays. I'm thinking of a ForEach loop to go through each device name, but I'm stuck there.

Here is the script I am using. (Run-Query is a function within the module I am loading). Server name has been changed to "ServerA" for our protection.

```
Import-Module TeamTools -DisableNameChecking

$YD=(Get-date (get-date).AddDays(-1) -Format "MM-dd-yyyy")
$TD=Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy"

$YData=Run-query -server ServerA -database Inventory -query "SELECT DeviceName,Powerstate FROM DeviceInventoryHistory WHERE SampleDate = '$YD' ORDER BY DeviceName"
$TData=Run-query -server ServerA -database Inventory -query "SELECT DeviceName,Powerstate FROM DeviceInventory WHERE SampleDate = '$TD' ORDER BY DeviceName"

$YData | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\YData.csv -NoTypeInformation
$TData | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\TData.csv -NoTypeInformation

$a=Import-CSV -Path C:\Temp\TData.csv
$b=Import-CSV -Path C:\Temp\YData.csv

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($a | Select-Object -Property 'DeviceName','PowerState') -DifferenceObject ($b | Select-Object -Property 'DeviceName','PowerState')
```

I have also tried to single out the entry from the array and yielded nothing:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($b | Where-Object {$_.DeviceName -eq 'Device B'}) -DifferenceObject ($a | Where-Object {$_.DeviceName -eq 'DeviceB'})
```

also tried it using the SQL data (without the CSV)

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($YData | Select-Object -Property 'DeviceName','PowerState' | Where-Object {$_.DeviceName -eq 'Device B'}) -DifferenceObject ($TData | Select-Object -Property 'DeviceName','PowerState' | Where-Object {$_.DeviceName -eq 'Device B'})
```

Here is the Device B from the CSV for proof that the are different:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $b | Where-Object {$_.DeviceName -eq 'Device B'}

DeviceName      Powerstate   
----------      ----------  
Device B        Powered Off

PS C:\Windows\system32> $a | Where-Object {$_.DeviceName -eq 'Device B'}

DeviceName      Powerstate  
----------      ----------  
Device B        Powered On
```

[See image of the two tables here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JKB9.png)

[First object in arrays a and b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA9PU.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you written some code already? If yes, please add that to your initial post. If no, here a hint how you could solve your task: [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-6) /  `Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($Table1 | Select-Object -Property 'Device Name', 'PowerState') -DifferenceObject ($Table2 | Select-Object -Property 'Device Name', 'PowerState')`

Comment: @Patrick I just added the code I am using, including the new compare-object you gave me. This however yields nothing. I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Could you check if the import csv was sucessfully and therefore the variable `$a` and `$b` are not empty? And could you upload a picture of the output from `$a[0]` and `$b[0]`?

Comment: I have added a picture of the first objects in arrays a and b. click the link in the bottom of the post. I have verified that the arrays aren't empty. I have verified the CSVs aren't empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I'd do this in SQL.

```
Select today.DeviceName, today.PowerState from
(SELECT DeviceName,Powerstate FROM DeviceInventoryHistory WHERE SampleDate = '$YD') as yest join (SELECT DeviceName,Powerstate FROM DeviceInventoryHistory WHERE SampleDate = '$TD') as today on yest.DeviceName = today.DeviceName where yest.Powerstate <> today.Powerstate
```

You take the query you used for today, and the only you used for yesterdays, JOIN them on what is the same (machine name or unique id or...), and then return the results where the power state is different.

You'd end up with a list of machines that changed, and what their current state is. If you want, you could also return yest.PowerState, but it's whatever today's isn't.

Comment: This is a MUCH better way to do this! I tested this and it works great! There is only one issue with your code, first line you write "today.PowerState as is from" this errors. However, removing "as is" works perfectly!

Comment: Whoops! I was originally going to return yesterday as "Was" and Today as "Is", but halfway through writing it realized that was silly. Thank you.